# Add space between files paths

Tags: text-processing, find

I have a list of folders and inside every folder I have the file " file.txt" which has the same name in all the folders. I wanted to collect the path for this file from all the folders and save it in a text file. In order to do so, I ran the following command in the parent folder :

```
find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt" > paths.txt
```

This command stored all the paths to this file from all the folders, in the file"path.txt " as follow:

```
a/b/c/1/file.txt
a/b/c/2/file.txt
a/b/c/3/file.txt
a/b/c/4/file.txt
a/b/c/5/file.txt
a/b/c/6/file.txt
a/b/c/7/file.txt
.
.
.
.
```

How can I create space between the lines in the file "path.txt" so it can show as follow:

```
/a/b/c/1/file.txt /a/b/c/2/file.txt /a/b/c/3/file.txt /a/b/c/4/file.txt /a/b/c/5/file.txt /a/b/c/6/file.txt /a/b/c/7/file.txt ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also take advantage of the fact that the shell strips newlines from command substitutions. So, instead of `find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt" > paths.txt`, you can do (note that you don't need the `$PWD`, it is the default value for `find`):

```
echo $(find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt") > paths.txt
```

or

```
printf '%s ' $(find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt") > paths.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

One more way, assuming GNU `find(1)`, just for fun:

```
find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt" -printf '%p '
```

Comment: +1. You can add a final newline to your output like this: `find "$PWD" -type f -name "file.txt" -printf '%p '; printf '\n'`

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the LF character with a space using the 'tr' command

```
tr '\012' ' ' < path.txt
```

This can be part of the original command:

```
find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt" | tr '\012' ' ' > paths.txt
```

Comment: @goro, if one of these answers solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

One simple way would be to pipe the `find` output through `xargs` (whose default action when no explicit command is given is to echo its arguments)

```
find $PWD -type f -name "file.txt" | xargs > paths.txt
```

Unlike simply replacing all the newlines with spaces, this preserves the final newline.

Answer (score 3):

You can use, `paste` too,

```
find . -type f -name "path.txt" -exec paste -d' ' -s {} \; > path.txt
```

Comment: This works on the *contents* of the files, not the filenames. Did you mean `find . -type f -name "*.tex" | paste -d' ' -s -`?

Comment: @muru it does work, in this case it does. I tested out before posting here. Even you can also test that.